# bison/flex parser into eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, bison, flex-lexer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to "merge" two of my projects.

-- I've got a project consisting of a bison/flex parser with its sources and its own makefile.

-- I've got an eclipse project(with its own sources) with a automatic makefile generation on itself.

What I have done so far :
On Eclipse

```
--click on my project>new Folder>link to folder in FS
--exclude the "main.cc" that is the main for the parser project when it is alone
```

Now i have access to my parser project files

```
(cpf.y, token.lex, heading.h, makefile)
```

Now i would like to add the interesting parts of my own makefile to the auto-generated makefile of my eclipse project ?? (I can't find the right preference location to do that)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in fact the solution is pretty simple :

--right click on the project

--under the c++ Build tag
--uncheck generate automatic makefile

Now the makefile you had will stay and you will be able to modify it without having it overwritten.

The only problem is that you will have to add manually every new file from your eclipse project (ie can't have autogenerate part for the eclipse project and manual part for the parser)